# Need to show only Weekday with Date UIDatePicker in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

Is there any way to show only week day with Date as: `MON 03-JUL` in `UIDatePicker` in iPhone.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, as far as I know there is no way to set a custom date format in UIDatePicker. Anyways, it wouldn't make much sense to display only the weekdays in a date picker, because you would end up with multiple entries for each weekday:

- Fri (3rd)
- Sat (4th)
- Sun (5th)
- ...
- Fri (10th)
- Sat (11th)
- ...

If you only want the user to pick a weekday (Mon-Sun), you could simply use a UIPickerView. And make sure you don't hard-code the weekday names, but rather use `- (NSArray *)weekdaySymbols` on `NSDateFormatter`. This will take the user's locale into account and returns an array of weekday names as strings:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray* weekdays = [dateFormatter weekdaySymbols];
// will return Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday (en_US locale)
```

Alternatively you can use `shortWeekdaySymbols`:

```
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSArray* weekdays = [dateFormatter shortWeekdaySymbols];
// will return Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat (en_US locale)
```